# Изменение текстовых полей на сайте с помощью C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Нужно с помощью C# авторизоваться на сайте и внести изменения на нём. В моём случае, сайт — настройки майнинг машины. Авторизоваться было не сложно, а вот с изменениями возникла 1 проблема. Сейчас я изменяю параметры машины вот так

```
HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(site.Url + "/cgi-bin/set_miner_conf.cgi") as HttpWebRequest;
....
req.Timeout = 30000;
req.Method = "POST";
byte[] send = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("url1 login1 psw1 url2 login2 psw2 url3 login3 psw3");
req.GetRequestStream().Write(send, 0, send.Length);
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
res.Close();
return site;
```

Но мне нужно изменять ещё и частоту машины, что сделать проблематично(для меня).
Собственно вопрос, какие ещё есть способы отправки настроек на сайт ?

<strike>Ещё 1 маленький вопрос, не смейтесь над ним</strike> Может есть какой-нибудь невидимый(не пробел) символ, который не будет отображаться в текстовом поле на сайте ?

Код странички: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WReMHjuSVoaeQ8q-jw2XTVBJOQdnB-O0/view

Comment: Почти всегда, сайт, при изменение полей отправляет данные на определенный адрес в определенном формате. Определите этот адрес через какой нибудь Fiddler, узнайте как правильно выглядит запрос и "эмулируйте" его.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, прожка помогла.